# Xamarin UI Test [AlertDialog]

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.uitest

Is it possible to query, tap the buttons, and get the message content of an AlertDialog in UITest? I have tried [this solution](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/90847/handling-pop-ups-with-xamarin-uitest) I can seem to query the AlertDialog itself [image: AlertDialog]
but whenever I tried to query `OK` or the id `message` I can't seem to retrieve it or it gives numerous results e.g. like this one: [image: AlertDialog2]

Is there another way for me to query an `AlertDialog` content? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your first query returns the AlertDialogLayout, you're looking for the TextView that is inside the AlertDialogLayout.
You should try to look for the [descendants](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery.Descendant/p/System.Int32/) of your AlertDialogLayout.

if you know the text you're looking for the easiest way to find it is

> app.Query(x => x.Class("AlertDialogLayout").Descendant().Text("YOUR TEXT"))

Comment: Thanks for the descendant method. I tried to experiment with this one, exactly what I am looking for.